# two node.js servers at one web address

Tags: node.js, http

I have two web application node.js servers and I need to have them under one web address.

It should work like this:

```
example.com/wa/*  -> redirect to example.com:pppp
others example.com/* -> redirect to example.com:qqqq
```

I have experimented with http proxy module, but it doesn't work, maybe the problematic part is the fact, both servers are https not http.

Comment: Is my answer correct? Ifso can you please mark so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Express you can do something like this

```
var express = require('express');  
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

app.use('/wa/*', function(req, res){
    req.redirect('example.com:pppp')
});

app.use('/*', function(req, res){
    req.redirect('example.com:qqqq')
}); 


http.createServer(app);
```

Not tested, but it should work.

Note:  The `/wa/*` route must come before the `/*` route. otherwise all requests will get redirected by the first middleware